# ExpansionTile - how to collapse other tiles, hide keyboard on press

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter, trying to build my first app.
my main app body contains a one level ExpansionTile list, which can be filterable by a searchbar.

I'm trying to implement the following behavior - 
after a user press a tile to reveal the expanded info
1. the keyboard, if present, should hide
2. previously open tile if expanded should collapse

I have tried using GestureDetector on the root widget with on tap function taking focus, but it does not detect tapping on tiles.
using expansionList onExpansionChanged seems logical but i don't understand how to use it

advice will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: You can see how to use that by reading the documentation. Also, it would be better if you include what you have tried so far in the form of code snippet